# Learning Haskell `parsec`: trying to rewrite `words` function as a basic exercise

Tags: haskell, parsec

This is an extremely basic question and I honestly feel a bit silly writing it.

**TL;DR:** How can I write a function which makes use of `parsec` library to mimic the behavior of the `words` function from `Data.List`?  An example of the intended behavior:

```
wordsReplica "I love lamp" = ["I","love","lamp"]
```

---

I just read the first couple pages of the Parsec chapter from `Real World Haskell` and it would be incredibly helpful to understand what constitutes a bare-minimum parsing function (one that does more than return the argument or return nothing).  (RWH's introductory example shows how to parse a multi-line CSV file...)

As such, I thought it'd be a useful, basic exercise to rewrite `words` using `parsec`...  It's turning out to be not so basic (for me)...

The following is my attempt; unfortunately it generates an "unexpected end of input" error (at runtime) no matter what I give it.  I've tried reading the descriptions/definitions of the simple functions in the `parsec` library on haskell.org but they aren't that illustrative, atleast for someone who's never done parsing of any kind before, including in other languages.

```
testParser :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
testParser input = parse dcParser "(unknown)" input
  where
    wordsReplica = endBy 
                    (sepBy 
                      (many (noneOf " "))
                      (char ' '))
                    (char ' ')
```

(Please pardon the lisp-y, non-pointfree presentation - when I'm learning about a new function, it helps me if I make the notation/structure super explicit.)

**Update:**
Here's something that's a step in the right direction (but still not quite there as it doesn't do numbers):

```
λ: let wordsReplica = sepBy (many letter) (char ' ')
λ: parse wordsReplica "i love lamp 867 5309"
Right ["i","love","lamp",""]
```

**Update 2:**

Seems like this function gets the job done, though am not sure how idiomatic it is:

```
λ: let wordsReplica = sepBy (many (satisfy(not . isSpace))) (char ' ')
wordsReplica :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m [[Char]]

λ: parse wordsReplica "" "867 5309 i love lamp %all% !(nonblanks are $$captured$$"

Right ["867","5309","i","love","lamp","%all%","!(nonblanks","are","$$captured$$"]
it :: Either ParseError [[Char]]
```

Comment: The first hint that something is wrong is that `words` returns a `[String]` but your function returns a `[[String]]`. The reason that it will always throw an error is that `endBy x (char ' ')` accepts strings whose last character is ' ', but the inner parser always consumes a ' ' character which appears at the end of the string. The fix is remove the `endBy .. (char ' ')` part and fix the type.

Comment: Well done. Note for the future that `words` isn't a parser, it's a splitting function. Parsing is best by specifying what's allowed rather than allowing anything that's not a separator. If anything goes, you're not parsing, so your next exercise should be something with rules about what is and isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update 2:**
>
> Seems like this function gets the job done, though am not sure how idiomatic it is.

It's fine, but it doesn't work as you intend:

```
> words "Hello      world"
["Hello","world"]

> parse wordsReplica "" "Hello      world"
Right ["Hello","","","","","","world"]
```

Not quite what you want. After all, a word should consist of at least one character. But if you change `many` to [`many1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:many1), you will notice another error:

```
> parse wordsReplicaMany1 "" "Hello      world"
Left (line 1, column 7):
unexpected " "
```

That's because your separating parser isn't greedy enough. Instead of parsing a *single* space, parse [as many as you can](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html):

```
nonSpace      = satisfy $ not . isSpace
wordsReplica' = many1 nonSpace `sepBy` spaces
```